# html5 drag and drop, getting dragged item position

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

is there any way to get the dragged item position in the `dragover`/`dragenter`/`dragleave` events in terms of X and Y related to the page? i know i can get the mouse position by calling `event.clientX` or `event.clientY`, but i would like to know the position of the floating element that created by the drag (the one that can be set by `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage()` function)

for example this code will print the mouse location when dragging, and not the real offset of the floating element:

```
function dragOver(event) {
   console.log(event.clientX
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of jQuery library you can achieve it,You can use console to print values, just to show you I'm printing positions on screen.

```js
$('#dragMe').draggable(
    {
        containment: $('body'),
        drag: function(){
            var position = $(this).position();
            var xPos = position.left;
            var yPos = position.top;
            $('#positionX').text('positionX: ' + xPos);
            $('#positionY').text('positionY: ' + yPos);
        },
         accept: '#dragMe',
        over : function(){
            $(this).animate({'border-width' : '5px',
                             'border-color' : '#0f0'
                            }, 500);
            $('#dragThis').draggable('option','containment',$(this));
        }
    
    });
```

```css
#dragMe {
    width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 2em 2em 2em;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

#dropMe {
    width: 12em;
    height: 12em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dragMe">
<p>DRAG ME</p>
    <ul>
        <li id="positionX"></li>
        <li id="positionY"></li>
        
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="dropMe"></div>
```